# Ruby on Rails: Set data in my model based on another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have an `item` model that has a `name` and a `price` (int). How could I make it so that when the user selects the `name` from a drop down the price will automatically be added to the db?

My `name` drop down is populated by a hash of this format: `THINGS = { 'Item 1' => 'item1', 'Item 2' => 'item2', etc }` I'm thinking that a large switch statement where I do something like

```
case s
    when hammer
        item.price = 15
    when nails
        item.price = 5
    when screwdriver
        item.price = 7
end
```

But I'm not sure where I would put this switch.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need push it in a before_save callback.

Inside this callback you check the name choose by your user and update the price

```
class Item

  before_save :update_price

  def update_price
    self.price = Product.find_by_name(self.name).price
  end
end
```

You can do in before_validation too if you want validate that your price is really define in your model

```
class Item

  before_validation :update_price
  validates_presence_of :price

  def update_price
    self.price = Product.find_by_name(self.name).price
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I wanted. I have a hash of items, and I need to associate the items from the hash with prices automatically. So basically, I have `THINGS = { 'A Hammer' => 'hammer', 'Some Nails' => 'nails', etc }`. What I need is a way to make is so that when 'hammer' is selected that a price of say 10 is set.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Thanks for the help!